# Is there any EyeSight or similar Support in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, gestures

EyeSight is the gesture control system without touching, video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58OgP7qFrXA) about *Gesture Control on the Lenovo X1 Carbon*. It is made by the Israel-based company. The feature should not be that difficult to make open-source. 
I have found no evidence about its support nor its open-source trival or plan: Debian [here](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Thinkpad/X1%20Carbon%204thGen%20PCIe_SSD/jessie), and Ubuntu review [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/48wp3o/x1_carbon_gen_4_ubuntu_minireview/). The company provides only Windows support now.

- ENAC. Some open-source attempt in old Ubuntus, review [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/multi-touch-in-ubuntu-using-a-webcam-and-your-hands-video/), but it seems to go outside of features provided in eyeSight.

I already sent an email to the company about the thing for the plan about Ubuntu support.

System: Ubuntu 16.04
Hardware: Lenovo X1 Carbon 4th gen

Comment: This is kinda advanced technology, like Gear VR or Kinect. It requires heavy R&D, which implies lots of time, money and personnel. And this R&D is driven by monetary and commercial reasons. Open-source usually relies on older or cheap hardware. Maybe you could persuade them into releasing some parts of their code under the GPL, like Google does with Chromium.

Comment: Just keep the faith and the patience. There was a time long ago when people had no (easy) alternative to Windows and (no) easy alternative to MS Office or to Internet Explorer. Can you even recall those days? Me neither.